# On Heroku, using Ruby on Rails, I want to identify individual web servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

When an application on Heroku is restarted, I would like to run some set-up tasks. However, I only want them to be run once.

If I put the tasks in an initializer and I have multiple web dynos set up, every dyno will run the task.

Is it possible to identify individual web dynos, and perhaps which is the first to spin up?

Comment: Are you talking about rake tasks? Do these set-up tasks affect the database? How would you run them if you ran these tasks manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can effectively (read: easily) assign any of the web processes unique ownership of the task management, since you never know which Dyno will shutdown first and how long before a new Dyno is spawned.

i.e.:

- If the first Dyno to be spawned is the owner, the "lock" on the task management might persist forever... even if the first Dyno closes down and other Dynos keep working.
- If the last Dyno to be spawned is the owner, if the owner dies no tasks will be performed until a new Dyno is spawned (which might take a while).

On the other hand, it seems your tasks are already in a persistent storage.

If tasks were checked out using database transactions, or (for non SQL storage) using a single threaded database such as Redis with a List, you could probably have all the Dynos performing the tasks without any task being performed more than once.

...

Another option, much favored for simplicity and for manageability, is to **use a single worker Dyno for your background tasks**. This Dyno will run a separate script, maybe sharing some code (and maybe not) with the web dynos.

If I were paying Heroku for multiple web Dynos, it would only make sense to deploy a worker Dyno for these tasks.

**EDIT** (you can ignore this, it's just a few more thoughts)

Even though the best solution is probably using a single worker Dyno, here are a few more thoughts.

***Runtime Flags***

This thought came to me since you implied that it would be nice to be able to scale down to a single Dyno...

You can use a runtime flag set in the [`Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#more-process-type-examples) which will tell a specific Dyno to process tasks or not process tasks. During runtime you can check the ARGV array for the flag.

Here is an experimental example Procfile with this distinction for a Rails application:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT run_tasks
onlyweb: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
```

When scaling, make sure you only scale the non task running Dynos:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1 onlyweb=4
```

In your application you can check this during runtime:

```
if ARGV.include? 'run_tasks'
   # initialize tasks for background handling.
end
```

***API to activate task handling***

Another possibility is to use a combination of [Kernel.at_exit](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit) and an HTTP API call.

This solution is a bit like setting up a digital game of "tag", and should probably include the following steps:

1. Create an HTTP route that will accept a "tag". Upon receiving such a request, the receiving Dyno will become the task executing Dyno (will become "IT"), initializing their tasks stack AND storing their UUID in the Database (you can use `require 'securerandom'; SecureRandom.uuid` for this).
2. Between each task, have the "IT" Dyno check if it's still "IT" by checking that their UUID is still the one in the Database.
3. Create an initialization sequence where the last web Dyno takes over the task handling (the new player always becomes "IT").
4. Setup a callback using [Kernel.at_exit](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit) that will attempt to "tag" a new Dyno in the event that the exiting Dyno is the task executing Dyno ("IT")...

These steps should ensure that there will always exist a task executing Dyno even while dynamically scaling up or down.

However, Now that I think of it, this might be considered a variant on the initial transactions concept, as the review of the UUID and the task being checked out of the task stack should probably both occurs within a transaction :-/

Comment: Thanks, good answer. In an ideal world, a separate worker would be the optimum. However, it's also nice to be able to use a single dyno with Heroku... ;)

Comment: The idea of using transactions is a good one, one I spent some time exploring. It still suffers from the problem of not knowing when a dyno is destroyed though. But that's outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Accepted as it's a solid answer to the question.

Comment: However, the more I think about it, the more I think that you're right. What I'm trying to do doesn't fit the multiple web dyno/no worker dyno model.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I thought that if all the Dynos are polling tasks, one task at a time using transactions, they can all work together and it doesn't matter which one closes or when... But I guess it did't work for you.... I have two more ideas, I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: Yeah, some kind of polling is the only way out I can see for this situation so far. There could be a solution in there... There is an extra dimension to the problem that I didn't put in the question (mainly for brevity). Also, this is all pretty much theoretical - I'm looking for a way to make a (successful) specific solution to a specific problem more general for a gem... If you have any more ideas I'd love to hear them, but don't bust a gut! :)

Comment: If you want more info in the ticket, just ask.

Comment: Mate, your solution with the runtime flags is awesome, I didn't even know that was possible.

Comment: Yep, the runtime flags answer is the best for me: I don't need to do any special development on the gem to allow it to scale with Heroku, it just requires documenting. (And I'll have to do some testing of course, which is a pleasurable excuse to use Heroku again.) Huge thanks. If I could double-tick I would.

Comment: Cool gem! ... Thanks for making me famous :-) Now I really hope this works ;-)

Comment: There's a whole testing phase to go through before I remove the dire warning. Thanks again! :)